# Fatal signal 11 when opening files using fopen(), fread() in NDK, but AAsset_read works fine

Tags: android, c, file-io, android-ndk, native-code

I'm trying to read wav files off the SD card for a audio sampler app I'm building using the NDK and 100% native code. I have a method which iterates through a predefined array containing the sample paths and streams each individually into a data buffer to be later played by OpenSL.

When I loaded the files as assets, using the following method:

```
int open_asset(AAssetManager* mgr, char* filename, int samp)
{

    assert(NULL != mgr);
    AAsset *asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, filename, AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);

    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "ASSET", "AAssetManager_open");

    if (NULL == asset)
    {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "ASSET", "Asset not found, loading aborted.");
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    oneshot_samples[samp].buffer_header = (unsigned short*) malloc(HEADER_SIZE);
    AAsset_read(asset, oneshot_samples[samp].buffer_header, HEADER_SIZE);

    unsigned short* fmttype;
    unsigned long* databytes;

    fmttype = (oneshot_samples[samp].buffer_header + 10);

    if (*fmttype != 0x1)
    {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "ASSET", "*fmttype not PCM, loading aborted.");
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    databytes = (oneshot_samples[samp].buffer_header + 20);

    oneshot_samples[samp].data_size = *databytes;

    oneshot_samples[samp].buffer_data = (unsigned short*) malloc(*databytes);
    AAsset_seek(asset, HEADER_SIZE, SEEK_SET);
    AAsset_read(asset, oneshot_samples[samp].buffer_data, oneshot_samples[samp].data_size);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "ASSET", "*fmttype: %x", *fmttype);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "ASSET", "*databytes: %x", *databytes);

    AAsset_close(asset);

    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "ASSET", "AAsset_close(asset)");

    return JNI_TRUE;
}
```

They load without a problem. But for my app, I want the user to be able to read samples from the SD Card too. I changed the file paths to a hard coded location on the SD Card (just for testing), and tried the following method using fopen() and fread():

```
void open_external_file(char* filepath, int samp)
{

    FILE* fp;
    oneshot_samples[samp].buffer_header = (unsigned short*) malloc(HEADER_SIZE);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "open_external_file",
                        "filepath: %s", filepath);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "open_external_file",
                        "size of filepath: %d", sizeof filepath);

    if ((fp = fopen(filepath, "r")) != NULL)
    {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "open_external_file", "fopen()");

        fread(oneshot_samples[samp].buffer_header, sizeof(unsigned short), HEADER_SIZE, fp);
    }

    unsigned short* fmttype;
    unsigned long* databytes;

    fmttype = (oneshot_samples[samp].buffer_header + 10);

    if (*fmttype != 0x1)
    {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "open_external_file", "*fmttype not PCM, loading aborted.");
    }

    databytes = (oneshot_samples[samp].buffer_header + 20);
    oneshot_samples[samp].data_size = *databytes;
    oneshot_samples[samp].buffer_data = (unsigned short*) malloc(*databytes);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "open_external_file", "*fmttype: %x", *fmttype);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "open_external_file", "*databytes: %x", *databytes);


    fseek(fp , HEADER_SIZE , SEEK_SET);
    fread(oneshot_samples[samp].buffer_data, sizeof(unsigned short), oneshot_samples[samp].data_size, fp);

    fclose(fp);
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "open_external_file", "fclose(fp);");
}
```

Which gives me the dreaded ANR and inevitable crash:

> 06-06 11:42:30.915: I/dalvikvm(7222): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   06-06 11:42:30.915: A/libc(7222): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1)

But the weird thing is that it happens seemingly quite randomly - there are 36 odd samples, and sometimes the error appears after just the 4th, and sometimes after 20 or so. After reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016057/android-ndk-crash-when-reading-writing-files), it appears it could be a segmentation fault, but I'm at a loss as to how it could be caused - or what the difference between the two methods is.

The values from the file header *fmttype and *databytes are returned 100% correctly every time.

I'm very new to C so it's quite possible I'm doing something obviously wrong - would really appreciate if someone more experienced could shed some light onto what the cause may be.

Update: I switched back using AAsset_read(), and am still getting:

> 06-06 12:33:50.393: I/dalvikvm(9755): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   06-06 12:33:50.393: I/dalvikvm(9755): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

But the files still load fine every time, and the app does not crash. The total size of my test samples is 48.4 MB for a 512 MB test tablet - could this be causing the issue? Still, if it was I don't see how using AAsset_read() would make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allocating `HEADER_SIZE` bytes:

```
(unsigned short*) malloc(HEADER_SIZE);
```

and then reading `HEADER_SIZE * 2` bytes into it, overflowing the buffer:

```
fread(oneshot_samples[samp].buffer_header, sizeof(unsigned short), HEADER_SIZE, fp);
```

(`fread()` multiplies `sizeof(unsigned short)` by `HEADER_SIZE`, doubling it.)

You do the same over-read again for `databytes`.  It doesn't fail for the android asset implementation because you're reading the correct amount of data in.  Fix it by changing `sizeof(unsigned short)` to `1`.

Unrelated: if fopen() returns NULL, you should probably return from the function, rather than processing uninitialized data.

The "signal 3" message just means the system is requesting a stack trace from the app, possibly because the main thread was busy and didn't respond to a message.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What I want to know is: `buffer_data` is an `unsigned short*`, each sample must 16 bits, i.e, OpenSL ES needs to read it that way. Would changing `sizeof(unsigned short)` to 1 affect the way the data gets arranged in the buffer? The data in the wave file is also arranged as little endian.

Comment: It won't change how the data is placed in the buffer.  Why `fread()` was declared this way is something of a mystery.  Other people have wondered about it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295994/what-is-the-rationale-for-fread-fwrite-taking-size-and-count-as-arguments

Comment: Interesting read. As you say, `fread(oneshot_samples[samp].buffer_data, sizeof(unsigned short), oneshot_samples[samp].data_size/2, fp)` and `fread(oneshot_samples[samp].buffer_data, 1, oneshot_samples[samp].data_size, fp)` gave me the exact same result. It's obvious why `AAsset_read()` was working and `fread()` not. Thanks for solving my problem.